# VSCode intellisense stopped working with js module import

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using javascript (es2015) imports the Intellisense refuses to work.

for example: `import {  } from 'react-router-dom'`
and hit [CTRL]+[SPACE] from within the curly braces of an `import` statement, there's no sign of suggestion, listing the module's exported entities.

When I try to import something exported with `export default` - there's also no suggestion.

my `jsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I'm using `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`  in order to handle export without default.
I overuse `exclude` section, I know ))

VSCODE about

```
Version: 1.31.1
Commit: 1b8e8302e405050205e69b59abb3559592bb9e60
Date: 2019-02-12T02:19:29.629Z
Electron: 3.1.2
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-45-generic
```

otherwise everything , and intellisense in general works well

Answer (score 1):

Two options that worked for me:

1. The object's "build action" is set to none. Change this to Compile (worked with .cs tho).
2. Close VS, delete the hidden ".vs" folder in explorer, next to your solution. Reopen VS.